# Listing and specifying packages in debootstrap

Tags: debootstrap

Is there a way to list the packages that debootstrap is going to download? Also, is there a way to tell debootstrap to download a user-specified list of packages?

Comment: A quick google gave me http://askubuntu.com/q/168158/15729 for the second part of your question. I've not checked to verify correctness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first, you use `--print-debs`, which shows you a list of packages that are going to be downloaded for a specific target. The second, you can use `--include`/`--exclude` switches for this task:

```
   --include=alpha,beta
          Comma separated list of packages which will be added to download
          and extract lists.

   --exclude=alpha,beta
          Comma separated list of packages  which  will  be  removed  from
          download  and extract lists.  WARNING: you can and probably will
          exclude essential packages, be careful using this option.
```

Notice that this is akin to "install base plus packages" or "install base minus packages". The base packages are always installed.

Comment: Well  OK, but I was hoping for some place to ediut a file, and to remove packes as well as add.